# Check if elements in array A belongs to array B

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to check if the integers in a large array A belongs to a smaller array B in an efficient way. I currently do this using a for loop, which is simply too slow for large A and B.

Any suggestions on how to do this in a more efficient way?

Current code:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.arange(10)
B=np.array([0,1,9])
isIn=np.zeros_like(A,dtype=bool)
for i in np.unique(B):
   isIn[A==i]=True
print(isIn)
```

```
[ True  True False False False False False False False  True]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) for this:

```
np.in1d(A, B)
# array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True])
```

Answer (score 0):

When interested in which values are intersecting: `numpy.intersect1d(A, B)`

Docs: [numpy.intersect1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)